# Problem with rotating armature with parent

Tags: armature

I want to rotate an armature with a connected parent. However, the result looks like the object is not connected correctly to the armature. When I move the armature, the end of the armature does not stay on the object to be moved.

Maybe you have an idea.

Here is an overview of my model:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My Model:

[image]

Comment: My Model:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=dMZkZEGG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/dMZkZEGG/)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see these 2 vertices are part of the vertex group called *Lasche2*, so the bone with the same name will move them:

[image]

Simply select them and remove them from this vertex group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. select your bones in pose mode, then pose -> clear transform -> all
2. select your object in object mode, shift select your armature, go in pose mode, select "Lasche1" and hit ctrl-p -> with automatic weights
3. do the same as 2 but with Lasche3
4. in object mode select your object, Tab -> edit mode
5. click "Lasche1" and "select", then remove, then select in face mode just this face and click "assign"

[image]

6. if you go in pose mode and move lasche1, it will work

[image]

7. do the same for Lasche3 with steps 4-5 with this face:

[image]

8. then you got:

[image]

9. select object in object mode -> tab -> edit mode, select lasche 2 -> press select, remove, select this face:

[image]

click on assign.

now it's ready working:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this was the solution!

Comment: you are welcome! if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. thank you!